Next js v14 Firebase Realtime Database not working
I am new in Next js and Firebase. I tried to connect my next js project to a Realtime Database and it don't work.
I followed the steps:

created next js app
created firebase project
added a web app to firebase project and executed "npm install firebase" in next js app folder
copied and paste the SDK in a firebaseConfig.js file located in app folder of next js app
created the realtime database using test mode configuration
added databaseURL in firebaseConfig.js file
push data to firebase using following code

const usersRef = ref(database, 'users');
const newDataRef = push(usersRef);
set(newDataRef, {
  user: props.email,
  password: props.password
});

I checked the console and there is no error.

Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

Also note that "not working" is hard to help with. If you get no error and no (relevant) log output, you'll want to debug locally and tell us the results of that. So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

In my case I fixed the problem by changing the firebaseConfig file extension from js to tsx.
